# Complex typing in Python

Tags: python, python-typing

I can't figure out how to properly define return types for the function.

Details:

This is the function that parses the settings object and returns a list of parameter values, it can be `tuple[str]`, `tuple[str, str]`, `tuple[Type[BaseCountryRatingComponent], bool]` whatever from the set of `[str, bool, Type[BaseCountryRatingComponent]]`.

Question:

How to properly define return types for `settings_traversal`?

```py
from typing import Union, Type

class BaseCountryRatingComponent:
    pass

class ComponentSetting:
    pass

class CompositeComponentSetting:
    pass

def settings_traversal(
    settings: list[Union["ComponentSetting", "CompositeComponentSetting"]],
    query_params: list[str],
) -> list[Union[str, bool, Type["BaseCountryRatingComponent"]]]:
    pass

def get_model_and_orm_key(
    self,
) -> list[tuple[Type["BaseCountryRatingComponent"], str]]:
    return settings_traversal(settings, ["model", "orm_key"])
```

Comment: it's hard to give you an an answer without seeing the full code of the helper functions, and on which lines did mypy report the errors. 
Could you share it as well?

Comment: @BarakFatal I provided an example of a helper function, also, the error is on the line with the return.

Comment: `Union[list[tuple[Any, ...]], list[Any]]` makes no sense - it's no different from plain `list[Any]` (`T1 | T` simplifies to `T`, if `T1` is a subtype of `T`).

Comment: @SUTerliakov Sure, but it does not solve the problem

Comment: Creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help 1) you to wrap your head around the crux of the problem and 2) others to understand what the actual problem is. There is a lot of irrelevant detail in your code right now and at the same time there are parts missing that would enable others to reproduce the error.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Thank you, for your help, I tried my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to manually write everything we need

```py
@classmethod
    def settings_traversal(
        cls,
        settings: list[Union[ComponentSetting, CompositeComponentSetting]],
        query_params: list[str],
    ) -> list[
        Union[
            str,
            tuple[Type[BaseCountryRatingComponent], str],
            tuple[str, str],
            tuple[str, str, bool],
            tuple[Union[str, bool, Type[BaseCountryRatingComponent]], ...],
        ]
    ]:
```

or simplifies the return types to the

```py
@classmethod
def settings_traversal(
    cls,
    settings: list[Union[ComponentSetting, CompositeComponentSetting]],
    query_params: list[str],
) -> list[Any]
```

Comment: agree here.  
@Olexiy Kutsenko I also think that in general if your function have so many return types, perhaps the correct way to handle it is to separate it to several functions

Comment: @BarakFatal Sure, but `settings_traversal` goes through the settings tree (each node is dataclass) and retrieves attributes specified in query_params. So in my case, there are no ways to decouple this function.